# Returning char * instead of string

Tags: c++, string, class, exception, char

How may I correct the following code in C++11:

```
    const char *what() const noexcept override {
        return "Mtm matrix error: Dimension mismatch: (" + std::to_string(mat1_height) + "," +
               std::to_string(mat1_width)
               + ") (" + std::to_string(mat2_height) + "," + std::to_string(mat2_width) + ")";
    }
```

As you can see I'm returning `string` instead of `const char*` but won't that be converrted automatically? and how to fix that?

**Note:** I want something to look like c++ code and not c using `sprintf` for example

Comment: "_I'm returning string instead of string_" No, you are returning `std::string` instead of `const char*`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius typo, will correct that

Comment: Any hints on this?

Comment: 1) "but won't that be converrted automatically?" No, why would it? They are 2 separate types. 2) "_Any hints on this?_" store `std::string` in your exception class, and return `.c_str ()` of that. Note: trying to return `.c_str ()` of the `std::string` constructed in this method, would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: On the one hand you are telling me to call .c_str () and on the other hand it would invoke undefined behaviour. that sounds like a contradiction

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius may you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but won't that be converrted automatically?

No.

> and how to fix that?

Store the string as a member, and call `c_str()` in `what`. Example:

```
struct descriptive_name : std::exception {
    std::string msg;

    descriptive_name(
       int mat1_width,
       int mat1_height,
       int mat2_width,
       int mat2_height)
         : msg(
           "Mtm matrix error: Dimension mismatch: ("
           + std::to_string(mat1_height)
           + ","
           + std::to_string(mat1_width)
           + ") ("
           + std::to_string(mat2_height)
           + ","
           + std::to_string(mat2_width)
           + ")"
           )
    {}

    const char *what() const noexcept override {
        return msg.c_str();
    }
};
```

Even better: Inherit from `std::runtime_error`, don't override `what`, and initialise the base class with the message string. Example:

```
struct descriptive_name : std::runtime_error {
    descriptive_name(
       int mat1_width,
       int mat1_height,
       int mat2_width,
       int mat2_height)
         : std::runtime_error(
           "Mtm matrix error: Dimension mismatch: ("
           + std::to_string(mat1_height)
           + ","
           + std::to_string(mat1_width)
           + ") ("
           + std::to_string(mat2_height)
           + ","
           + std::to_string(mat2_width)
           + ")"
           )
    {}
};
```

Comment: Please read the comments, someone told: Note: trying to return .c_str () of the std::string constructed in this method, would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @Daniel That is why you're not supposed to construct the string in that method. Construct it in the constructor. That is where the members are initialised.

Comment: @Daniel I added examples.

Comment: What' the difference between inheriting from exception or runtime_error...

Comment: THANKS, last thing may you explain why the what I did before would cause undefined behaviour and this won't?

Comment: @Daniel The `std::string` that you created is a temporary object. The temporary object doesn't exist outside of that function. You are attempting to return a pointer to (buffer owned by) the object. That pointer will always be dangling and attempting to access the string would result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple because you are returning a temporary object which you are trying to convert into a pointer. You CAN do that by using

```
const char *what() const noexcept override {
        return ("Mtm matrix error: Dimension mismatch: (" + std::to_string(mat1_height) + "," +
               std::to_string(mat1_width)
               + ") (" + std::to_string(mat2_height) + "," + std::to_string(mat2_width) + ")").c_str();
    }
```

but after converting the object will be destroyed and this will result in the actual data being deleted. Instead you can just copy the data.

```
const char* what()
{
    std::string temp = "Mtm matrix error: Dimension mismatch: (" + std::to_string(mat1_height) + "," +
                       std::to_string(mat1_width)
                       + ") (" + std::to_string(mat2_height) + "," + std::to_string(mat2_width) + ")";
    char * p = new char[temp.size()+1]{};
    strcpy(p,temp.data());
    return p;
}
```

Just note that this is inefficient since you are creating and destroying and object and there is an extra copy which might be slow. Also you must remember to delete the `char*` after using this function.

Comment: _Instead you can just copy the data._ Yeah, but now you have a probable memory leak. (I suspect the caller doesn't expect that the returned value has to be deleted. And, it might be that it must not be deleted for other `override`s.)

Comment: Well best case scenario you just use the std::string

Comment: May someone please show a solution that won't leak memory or cause problems

Comment: @Daniel What about [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62573709/7478597)? I.e. store the `std::string` in the exception class itself. Then it is safe to return a `.c_str()` in `what() const` as the exception instance is managing the life-time of the `std::string` sufficiently.