# Exceptions Using Inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, exception

I wrote the following code:

```
class GameException : public mtm::Exception {
};

class IllegalArgument : public GameException {
public:
    const char *what() const noexcept override {
        return "A game related error has occurred: IllegalArgument";
    }
};

class IllegalCell : public GameException {
public:
    const char *what() const noexcept override {
        return "A game related error has occurred: IllegalCell";
    }
};
```

How may I use inheritance here to prevent some code duplication? As you can see I'm returning the same sentence but with different ending (Which is the class name).
I though about implementing GameException as the following:

```
class GameException : public mtm::Exception {
     std::string className;
public:
    const char *what() const noexcept override {
        return "A game related error has occurred: "+className;
    }
};
```

But how may I change the value of className for the rest of my classes?
Plus, I'm getting the error:

> No viable conversion from returned value of type
> 'std::__1::basic_string' to function return type 'const char *'

Comment: FYI: [SO: Returning char * instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62573397/7478597) (Very similar question from yesterday.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `char [] + std::string` yields a `std::string` but the method is delcared to return a `const char *`.

To avoid problems with returning a pointer to temporary, I would suggest this:

```
class GameException : public mtm::Exception {
     std::string message;
public:
    GameException(const std::string& pref) 
      : message("A game related error has occurred: " + pref)
    {}
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};
```

Derived classes then only need

```
struct some_excpetion : GameException {
     some_exception() : GameException("some_exception") {}
};
```

PS: Inheriting from `std::runtime_error` can be more convenient, because it already implements `what()` and comes with a constructor that takes the message to be returned by `what()`. You can basically remove your `GameException` and inherit from `std::runtime_error` instead.

Comment: @Josh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/c-what-does-the-colon-after-a-constructor-mean

Comment: @Josh fyi (not sure if it was yours, but...) the "thanks" feature doesnt do anything. Best way to say "thanks" is still voting

Comment: Voted your answer, sorry for the delay